# To express a vector as a linear combination of vectors, do the vectors need to linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For example, write (-3,4,1) as a linear combination of (1,2,1) (8,1,2) and (4,3,2)

Is this possible considering these vectors are not linearly independent?
I ask this because when constructing these into a matrix and running a reduced row echelon form, I do not have a clear answer, and I figure this is the reason.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: what do you mean by you do not have a clear answer, can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Sure. When I do my reduced row echelon form, I only have two pivots, despite the set containing three vectors. Therefore I concluded that my set was not linearly independent.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To answer the title question, *some* vectors could be written as a linear combination of vectors that are not linearly independent; for example, $(10,10,10)=3(1,1,1)+2(2,2,2)+1(3,3,3)$

Comment: No, the vectors don’t need to be linearly independent. Not getting a “clear answer” reflects the fact that the linear combination might not be unique, as it is when they’re linearly independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to determine whether it is possible to write $(-3,4,1)$ as a linear combination of $(1,2,1), (8,1,2),$ and $(4,3,2),$ the standard approach is to put these vectors together as the columns of a matrix, then row reduce. In particular, we have
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 8 & 4 & -3\\ 2 & 1 & 3 & 4\\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \end{array}\right)
\leadsto \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{7}{3}\\ 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
$$
Because the last column of the row-reduced matrix is not a pivot column, it is possible to write $(-3,4,1)$ as a linear combination of the other three vectors.  In particular: we see that in the row-reduced matrix, the last column can be written as $\frac 73$ of the first column added to $- \frac 23$ of the second column.  Because this holds for the row-reduced matrix, it also holds for the original matrix. That is, we have
$$
(-3,4,1) = \frac 73 \cdot (1,2,1) - \frac 23 \cdot (8,1,2).
$$

Comment: That explains it perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be linearly independent.

The RREF is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{7}{3}\\ 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The system is consistent.

As noted, there are only two pivot columns and that means we have a free variable. Let $x_3=t$, then we have

$x_1=\frac73-\frac43t$ and $x_2=-\frac23-\frac13t$.

Each possible $t$ gives you a possible linear combination.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly.

In your example, suppose the coeffients are a b and c.
Then we want to solve the equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 8 & 4\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\4 \\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Because the base vectors are dependant, the equation has no solutions that can be expressed as $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: It is not true that "if the columns of a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ are linearly dependent, then $Ax = b$ never has a solution".  However, this is what you seem to be saying.

Comment: Thank you! I was wrong.